# how to formulate following query in linq dynamically

Tags: linq

I wanted to formulate 1) query dynamically as shown in 2)

1)

```
Select col1, Sum(col2)
    from t1
    where col3 = 1
      and co11 between '01 jan 2009' and '31 dec 2013'
    group by co11
```

2)
And I would like to formulate above as following in 2012 (linq to entity)

```
 " select "+ @selectclause + " from t1  where " + whereclause
```

somebody suggested me, that the above query can be formulated  using http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Can any body formulate it using the `System.linq.Dynamic` or `System.Linq.Expression`? I am not able to do it due to lack of time.

I was trying some thing like following using `System.Linq.dynamic`

```
var var1 = context.table1.Where(strWhereClause)
.Where(i => i.co11  >= dtDateFrom && i.co11  <= dtDateTo).GroupBy("new(" + varGroupBy + ")").Select("new(" + varAggregateCol + ")");
```

Please also tell me if my bunch of queries can be forumlated by `System.Linq.Expression`
then should I use `System.Linq.Dynamic` or shouldI give priority to `System.Linq.Expression`.

yours sincerley

Comment: DynamicLinq is the best and simplest solution! creating expression tree is too complicated...

Comment: so what not work in you current solution?

Comment: I have tried many things, but could not get, mean while i am tring other things.

Comment: Please suggest if any one has any answer, i am using vs 2012

Comment: Please tel me is can i use system.Linq.Dynamic of 2013 into 2012

Comment: You could try this https://github.com/dkackman/SqlLinq. Is mostly experimental but should be able to parse the provided SQL assuming you're talking about linq to objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what this would look like:

```
var query = t1.Where("col3 = 1 AND col1 >= @0 AND col1 <= @1", dtDateFrom, dtDateTo)
            .GroupBy("col1")
            .Select(varAggregateCol)
```

While the standard Dynamic Linq library simply returns a IQueryable that is hard to use, I've been maintaining an updated library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library) that returns IQueryable{dynamic} (assuming you are using .NET 4.0+), allowing you to easily access the resulting members dynamically.